# Unstacking a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe with two columns called 'column' and 'value' that looks like this:

**Dataframe 1:**

```
                   column  value
0                  column1     1
1                  column2     1
2                  column3     1
3                  column4     1
4                  column5     2
5                  column6     1
6                  column7     1
7                  column8     1
8                  column9     8
9                  column10    2
10                 column1     1
11                 column2     1
12                 column3     1
13                 column4     3
14                 column5     2
15                 column6     1
16                 column7     1
17                 column8     1
18                 column9     1
19                 column10    2
20                 column1     5
..                      ...   ...
```

I want to transform this dataframe so that it looks like this:

**Dataframe 2:**

```
    column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10
    0       1      1       1       1       2       1       1       1        8      2
    1       1      1       1       3       2       1       1       1        1      2
    2       5      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..       ..     ..
    ..      ..     ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..      ..       ..     ..
```

Now I know how to do it the other way around. If you have a dataframe called `df` that looks like **dataframe 2** you can stack it with the following code:

```
df = (df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).rename_axis(['column']).reset_index(name='value'))
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to go back!

**Question:** How do I manipulate **dataframe 1** (unstack it, if that's a word) so that it looks like **dataframe 2**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with counter `Series` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
g = df.groupby('column').cumcount()
df1 = df.set_index([g, 'column'])['value'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
column  column1  column10  column2  column3  column4  column5  column6  \
0             1         2        1        1        1        2        1   
1             1         2        1        1        3        2        1   
2             5         0        0        0        0        0        0   

column  column7  column8  column9  
0             1        1        8  
1             1        1        1  
2             0        0        0
```

Last if need sorting by numeric value of columns names use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for integers, convert them and get positions of columns by [`argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.argsort.html) - last reorder by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df1.iloc[:, df1.columns.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).argsort()]
print (df1)
column  column1  column2  column3  column4  column5  column6  column7  \
0             1        1        1        1        2        1        1   
1             1        1        1        3        2        1        1   
2             5        0        0        0        0        0        0   

column  column8  column9  column10  
0             1        8         2  
1             1        1         2  
2             0        0         0
```